# Grails changing datasource at runtime

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I was asked to implement a logic for having separate domains for a separate user (assuming he will have his own database) means all the domains will be mapped to different database at runtime. **Sounds silly i know**

How can i change the datasouce(persistence configuration file) after logIn of user while datasource
 are supposed to load at startup time of application.

Is it possible somehow?

**NOTE:** I want to change datasource of some domain to another datasource at runtime one at a time.

Comment: hey sachin,,i am facing similar kind of issue..can you please ping me on vishal.sujanian@gmail.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map multiple data sources in your `DataSource.groovy` file and you can create multi talented domain classes and then you can perform any `CRUD` operations among these data sources at runtime.

#### References

- http://www.jellyfishtechnologies.com/configure-multiple-datasources-in-grails/
- http://www.jellyfishtechnologies.com/querying-on-multiple-datasource-in-grails/
- http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources

Comment: what i mean say one domain is mapped to a table in database1, is it possible for same domain to map to a table in database2 at runtime???

Comment: Yes, it is possible to map same domain with different datasource like this `datasources(['lookup', 'auditing'])`. You can map domain class with all databases `datasource 'ALL'`  in domain class.   read http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources for more clarity.

Comment: Thanks for taking interest, but i dont want to point my domain to 2 datasource at same time, i want to change datasource of my domain to another not the same not the both.

Comment: Multiple datasources(multi talented domain class) is an awesome approach to achieve the requirement. A domain is capable to serve all the data sources. Just tell the domain in which data source you want to perform the CRUD operations at run time.

Comment: @user1690588 your approach really seems interesting but how to make multi tenanted domain classes. Can you post some links on it. Thnks btw

Comment: See the links given in the answer. Create multiple data sources and when want to perform some operation in a particular data source then just change the data source name. `def userClass = User.class; User user = userClass.${dataSourceName}.findByName('amit')`.

Comment: Can i add a new datasource at runtime?

Comment: No, you can not add data source at run time.