# Modify Grail plugin Domain Class data-source in dependent application

Tags: grails, configuration, grails-orm

I have multiple plugins with Grails domain classes that are stored in separate databases. I want to be able to configure within the dependent project what sources each class comes from. It seems like a similar question is here:

[Grails changing datasource at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19930204/grails-changing-datasource-at-runtime)

Is it still not possible to add additionaly sources to a class at runtime? And, I don't necessarily need to do it at runtime either. Just configure the class in the dependent Grails application. The method for setting this up (http://www.grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources) requires direct access to the class definitions, and I'd rather avoid having to do that.

Comment: What you should consider is giving your domain classes generic names for the data sources and re-configuring the datasources for each name per project. That's the correct way to handle this. E.g. domains always use sourceA and sourceB but depending on your project sourceA and sourceB could point to anywhere (even the same place) when you configure the datasource.

Comment: Is there anything that can be done if one does not own the domain project and cannot alter it directly? I can do this with some of them. But there are data plugins owned by other teams in the company. It would be nice to not have to coordinate these changes between all of us. Thanks for your reply.